# Editable pdf in AngularJs(Client side)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

How can I edit the pdf on my website in AngularJs(Javascript)?

I am unable to find any library which compatible with AngularJs/Javascript.

I tried PDFHelper(but It's Software) and pdf.js(etc) through which you only view pdf not edit.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am looking for the same, have you found it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jsdPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).You can put a wrapper on this js project into a service that you call throughout your app. Not a best practice ,But you can make use of it.

Comment: I want to edit pdf at client side but this module doesn't provide to edit pdf.